# Create a field in a table using Command Prompt *Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, field

How do I create a new field in an existing table using the Ruby command prompt?

I created the model (and migrated it) but I forgot to add a field - how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a new migration to add a new column to table.

```
rails g migration add_column_name_to_table_name column_name:type
```

This will create a migration class like below:

```
#config/migration/20150304121554_add_column_name_to_table_name.rb
class AddColumnNameToTableName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :table_name, :column_name, :type
  end
end
```

Here, column_name, table_name and type should be your desired name and type. Than run `rake db:migrate` command.

Comment: do I replace add_column_name_to_table_name with (if the name of my table = show and field = category) to add_category_to_show category:references ?

Comment: Yes, you should do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make changes in your situation:

- Roll back the last migration
- Add the new field in a new migration

Undoing the last migration should only be done if you have not yet pushed the migration to a public server. Here's how to do it:

1. Run `rake db:rollback`
2. Add the new field to the same migration file you originally used
3. Run `rake db:migrate`

**Option 2:**

To add the field in a new migration:

```
rails g migration AddFieldNameToTableName
```

For example, if your field is `name` and your table is `users`, you would run:

```
rails g migration AddNameToUsers
```

This will create a new migration file whose name starts with today's date and ends with `add_name_to_users.rb`. Open the file and add the field using the `add_column` command, like this:

```
class AddNameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :name, :string
  end
end
```

Save the file, then run `rake db:migrate`.

I encourage you to read the [Rails migrations guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) to learn more.